# SortValueConverter not working correctly when order of an existing item is changed

Tags: aurelia

I would like to list the content of my array on my view. This must be sorted. Below is my first implementation.

**app.js:**

```
export class App {

    items: Array = [
        { order: 2, color: 'Red' },
        { order: 5, color: 'Green' },
        { order: 1, color: 'Blue' },
        { order: 4, color: 'Yellow' }
    ];
    get sortedItems() {
        var elms = this.items.slice(0);
        return elms.sort(function (a, b) {
            return a.order - b.order;
        });
    }
    addElement() {
        var elm = { index: 4, order: 3, color: 'Brown' };
        this.items.push(elm);
    }
    changeElement() {
        var elm = this.items.find(x => x.color == 'Blue');
        elm.order = 7;
    }
}
```

**app.html:**

```
<template>  

  <ul>
    <li repeat.for="item of sortedItems">
      ${item.order} - ${item.color}
    </li>
  </ul>

  <button click.trigger='addElement()'>Add</button>
  <button click.trigger='changeElement()'>Change</button>

</template>
```

https://gist.run/?id=fadff61b1159fd1d4dcfaf1ed4c4990e

It works as expected.

- At runtime, the list is sorted
- When a new item is added in the array, it is correctly displayed (sorted) in the view
- When the order value of an existing item is changed, it is correctly adjusted (sorted) in the view

But now I would like to use a ValueConverter for sorting my list. So below is my second implementation.

**app.js:**

```
export class App {

    items: Array = [
        { order: 2, color: 'Red' },
        { order: 5, color: 'Green' },
        { order: 1, color: 'Blue' },
        { order: 4, color: 'Yellow' }
    ];
    get allItems() {
      return this.items;
    }
    addElement() {
        var elm = { index: 4, order: 3, color: 'Brown' };
        this.items.push(elm);
    }
    changeElement() {
        var elm = this.items.find(x => x.color == 'Blue');
        elm.order = 7;
    }
}
```

**app.html:**

```
<template>

  <require from="./sort"></require>

  <ul>
    <li repeat.for="item of allItems | sort:'order':'ascending'">
      ${item.order} - ${item.color}
    </li>
  </ul>

  <button click.trigger='addElement()'>Add</button>
  <button click.trigger='changeElement()'>Change</button>

</template>
```

**sort.js:**

```
export class SortValueConverter {
  toView(array, propertyName, direction) {
    let factor = direction === "ascending" ? 1 : -1;
    return array.sort((a, b) => {
      return (a[propertyName] - b[propertyName]) * factor;
    });
  }
}
```

https://gist.run/?id=06f97d4b12b43c2fd3d727fb49edd1c0

With this implementation the sort is not working after changing the order of the Blue element.

- At runtime, the list is sorted
- When a new item is added in the array, it is correctly displayed (sorted) in the view
- BUT when the order value of an existing item is changed, it is NOT correctly adjusted (sorted) in the view

How can I proceed to have my array correctly sorting elements when value of an existing item is changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use a [`signal` on the binding](https://aurelia.io/docs/binding/binding-behaviors#signal), and whenever you mutate an item in the array - emit a signal and the binding will kick in again.

Comment: You are right. Thanks. I updated my GistRun: https://gist.run/?id=06f97d4b12b43c2fd3d727fb49edd1c0

Answer (score 1):

## Pass `length` as an argument

Aurelia observes all arguments to value converters and functions. In this case, even though the array is being mutated, it is still the same array and thus Aurelia doesn't recompute. Passing the length will cause it to change when the array is mutated.

```
repeat.for="item of allItems | sort:'order':'ascending':allItems.length"
```

Comment: still: changing a property of an element inside the array will not re-trigger the sort.

Comment: That's true, but not a common use case. Signal adds a lot of complexity and overhead that you don't need in 9 out of 10 cases.